# Как преобразовать String в Date?

Tags: java, строки, дата, simpledateformat

Есть две строки на русском языке:

1. `Сегодня, 12:00`
2. `1 сентября 2017`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как их преобразовать в `Date`? Буду благодарен за кусок кода или полезную ссылку. Меня интересует преобразование именно этих двух строк. Я только недавно начал учить java. Знания `Date` и `SimpleDateFormat` еще до конца не устаканились :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.С использованием `LocalDateTime` и поиска времени по шаблону:

```
String string = "Сегодня, 12:00";
LocalTime timePart = null;
LocalDate datePart = null;
String regex = "([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(string);     
if (m.find()) timePart = LocalTime.parse(m.group(0));       
if (string.contains("Сегодня")) datePart = LocalDate.now();

LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.of(datePart, timePart);
Date out = Date.from(date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
System.out.println(out); // Wed Sep 06 12:00:00 MSK 2017
```

Для `Вчера` можно использовать `datePart = LocalDate.now().minus(Period.ofDays(1));`

2.

```
String string = "1 сентября 2017";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy", new Locale("ru"));
Date date = format.parse(string);
System.out.println(date); // Fri Sep 01 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2017
```

Comment: Отлично, все работает!)
А подскажите, пожалуйста, тогда следующий вопрос. немного не понимаю.
Вот я получаю строки "Сегодня, >рандомное время<" и "Вчера, >рандомное время<"
Как мне в этом случае действовать?

Comment: @YaPV Вам нужно проверять строку на вхождение подстроки `Сегодня` или `Вчера` и дальше подставлять нужную дату. Мой пример для `Сегодня`, вот тут посмотрите как получить `Вчера`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425236/get-yesterdays-date-using-date или вот так `datePart = LocalDate.now().minus(Period.ofDays(1));`

Comment: Спасибо большое!